# Unable to view pages on LOCALHOST under IIS 7 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iis

I cannot view pages on localhost. Every time I try to open them, IE reports "This page cannot be displayed" and provides no further details. I'm trying to figure out what's going on and how to resolve it.

- Windows Firewall is completely disabled.
- System (Process ID 4) is listening on Port 80, as verified with TCPView.
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled IIS, as well as .NET 4.5 and WCF, to no avail.
- I cannot even browse to a simple HTML file in the root of INETPUB\WWWROOT.

I've tried just about every fix I can find out there, all to no avail. I suspect that *something* is rejecting the requests, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I will provide whatever details you need.

Comment: "I've tried just about every fix I can find out there, all to no avail." To avoid us suggesting the same things you've already tried, please edit your question and tell us exactly what you've tried already.

Comment: If you Telnet to Localhost on port 80, does it connect?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, It does. I did find the error, finally. My hosts file was missing a line for the loopback address ([::1]). I added and I can now browse to localhost.

Comment: Nice! You should add that as an answer to help future visitors.  (Answering your own questions is a good thing ;) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. My hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc) was missing an entry for the loopback address. I added the following line to the file and everything came up roses:

```
[::1] localhost
```